# Bit slice format of 4x4 s-boxes?

Tags: block-cipher, symmetric, s-boxes, bitslicing

I have studied bit-sliced implementation in SERPENT block cipher and I need to use this technique to implement some 4x4 s-boxes. I couldn't find any procedure to obtain bit-sliced format in any paper or document. I really need this method to use. Please explain me how to do this and what method or procedure I can use from beginning to end?

Comment: You might be interested in [this paper](http://skew2011.mat.dtu.dk/proceedings/Finding%20Optimal%20Bitsliced%20Implementations%20of%204%20to%204-bit%20S-boxes.pdf)

Comment: I read this. But I couldn't understand the method and it didn't have any sample.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem to me

Comment: Does [http://www.ii.uib.no/~osvik/pub/aes3.pdf] help you?